# Android SDK Manager in Eclipse find not path

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I open the sdk manager in eclipse, error.

```
[SDK Manager] 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
[SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
[SDK Manager]  at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:351)
[SDK Manager]  at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:325)
[SDK Manager]  at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:125)
[SDK Manager]  at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:108)
[SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
[SDK Manager]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[SDK Manager]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[SDK Manager]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[SDK Manager]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[SDK Manager]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[SDK Manager]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[SDK Manager]  ... 4 more
```

This is my computer configuration.

```
ANDROID_SDK_HOME - C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk

ANDROID_SWT - %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\tools\lib\x86_64

CLASS_PATH - .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
```

Path -

```
C:\Windows\System32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\platform-tools;%SystemRoot%system32;%SystemRoot%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\bin;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools
```

.android files are located on the

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk
```

eclipse files are located on the

```
C:\Android\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse
```

jdk and jre files are located on the

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The first line shows that it can not find C:\Program which is why it gives error.
Your path has a space in it but it get parsed as two separate words `C:\Program` and `Files`,

To avoid this, based on your windows version, you can use these parameters in your while setting your `JAVA_HOME` :

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
```

or

```
%programfiles%\Java\jdk1.6.0_35
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. It's is simply because for android.bat in path {Directory Path}:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\android.bat in line 73, path ANDROID_SWT is not set properly.

Follow following steps to correct it:
1. Set the Environment Variable in Windows as Computer->Right Click->Properties->Click on left Advanced System Setting ->Click New Under System Variable-> Variable Name: ANDROID_SWT-> Variable Value ->D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\x86 (Note: This is where I had my swt.jar; swt.jar is place in /tools/lib//swt.jar
 is x86 or x86_64)

Once, path is set correctly, run the cmd again.